# How to push `dict` column into Redshift SUPER type column using `pandas.to_sql`?

Tags: json, pandas, sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift, sqldatatypes

AWS Redshift allows `SUPER` datatype in columns to hold json like data.
This [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/super-overview.html#:%7E:text=Rapid%20and%20flexible%20insertion%20of,of%20SUPER%20into%20conventional%20columns.) explains how to do it via the `COPY` function or using an `INSERT` function. The `INSERT` function requires `JSON_PARSE` function to be applied to the column value in the statement. This is shown [here](https://redshift-immersion.workshop.aws/lab15.html#parsing-json-documents-to-super-columns).
How am I able to use `pandas.DataFrame.to_sql` function to implement the above behaviour?

```
df.to_sql('table', connection, schema='my_schema', if_exists='append', dtype=type_dict)
```

The above is used to execute `INSERT` statements.
I tried using

```
type_dict = {
'my_json_column' = sqlalchemy.types.JSON,
}
```

However, I am seeing my redshift table having "\" characters within the string. Therefore the `SUPER` column defined in the target redshift table has string values and not json.
How can i leverage `pandas.DataFrame.to_sql` function to implement `JSON_PARSE` functionality in redshift and is there no way around writing `INSERT` queries?

GENUINE REQUEST TO COMMUNITY : Please be friendly when you answer this and feel free to comment in if the question is not clear to you. I will revisit and reiterate.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use SqlAlchemy types and SqlAlchemy-Redshift dialect. In addition, you need to enable `psycopg2` extensions.

```py
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy_redshift as sar
from psycopg2.extensions import register_adapter
from psycopg2.extras import Json

register_adapter(dict, Json)
register_adapter(list, Json)

rs_url = 'redshift+psycopg2://username:password@cluser_url.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/db_name'

dict_types={
    'responseID': sa.types.INTEGER(),
    'surveyID': sa.types.INTEGER(),
    'surveyName': sa.types.NVARCHAR(length=65535),
    'timestamp': sa.types.DateTime(),
    'location': sar.dialect.SUPER()
}

df = pd.read_json('my_file.json')
df.to_sql('table_name', con='connection_string', 
    chunksize=100, method='multi', if_exists='replace', index=False, schema='schema_name', dtype=dict_types)
```

Comment: i got an error:
'PGTypeCompiler' object has no attribute 'visit_SUPER'
Compiler <sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.base.PGTypeCompiler object at 0x1544dc160> can't render element of type SUPER