# 'PGTypeCompiler' object has no attribute 'visit_SUPER'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

Very little hope here :)
But i'm getting this error when trying to upload a pandas table with a json column as described in this other SO post:
[How to push `dict` column into Redshift SUPER type column using `pandas.to_sql`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68940899/how-to-push-dict-column-into-redshift-super-type-column-using-pandas-to-sql)

`AttributeError: 'PGTypeCompiler' object has no attribute 'visit_SUPER'`

I tried googling the error and it came back with all of two results, so I guess I'm like the third person ever to run into this.
But if anyone by chance knows anything about this, I'd super appreciate any help.

```
from psycopg2.extensions import register_adapter
from psycopg2.extras import Json
from sqlalchemy_redshift import dialect
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, types
import pandas as pd
import json

register_adapter(dict, Json)
register_adapter(list, Json)

RS_creds = {}

RS_creds['host'] = %env RS_DATA_HOST
RS_creds['user'] = %env RS_DATA_USER
RS_creds['pass'] = %env RS_DATA_PASS
RS_creds['port'] = %env RS_DATA_PORT
RS_creds['db'] = %env RS_DATA_DB

test = pd.DataFrame([[1, json.dumps({"a": "A1", "b": "B1"})], [2, json.dumps({"a": "A2", "b": "B2"})]])
test.columns = ['x', 'y']
test_dict_types = {'x': types.INTEGER(), 'y': dialect.SUPER()}

url = f"postgresql://{RS_creds['user']}:{RS_creds['pass']}@{RS_creds['host']}:5439/{RS_creds['db']}"

engine = create_engine(url)

test.to_sql('test', engine, schema = 'test', index = False, dtype = test_dict_types})
```

traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py:77, in _generate_compiler_dispatch.<locals>._compiler_dispatch(self, visitor, **kw)
     76 try:
---> 77     meth = getter(visitor)
     78 except AttributeError as err:

AttributeError: 'PGTypeCompiler' object has no attribute 'visit_SUPER'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

UnsupportedCompilationError               Traceback (most recent call last)
File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py:4534, in DDLCompiler.visit_create_table(self, create, **kw)
   4533 try:
-> 4534     processed = self.process(
   4535         create_column, first_pk=column.primary_key and not first_pk
   4536     )
   4537     if processed is not None:

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py:499, in Compiled.process(self, obj, **kwargs)
    498 def process(self, obj, **kwargs):
--> 499     return obj._compiler_dispatch(self, **kwargs)

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py:82, in _generate_compiler_dispatch.<locals>._compiler_dispatch(self, visitor, **kw)
     81 else:
---> 82     return meth(self, **kw)

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py:4568, in DDLCompiler.visit_create_column(self, create, first_pk, **kw)
   4566     return None
-> 4568 text = self.get_column_specification(column, first_pk=first_pk)
   4569 const = " ".join(
   4570     self.process(constraint) for constraint in column.constraints
   4571 )

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/base.py:2734, in PGDDLCompiler.get_column_specification(self, column, **kwargs)
   2733 else:
-> 2734     colspec += " " + self.dialect.type_compiler.process(
   2735         column.type,
   2736         type_expression=column,
   2737         identifier_preparer=self.preparer,
   2738     )
   2739     default = self.get_column_default_string(column)

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py:533, in TypeCompiler.process(self, type_, **kw)
    532 def process(self, type_, **kw):
--> 533     return type_._compiler_dispatch(self, **kw)

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py:79, in _generate_compiler_dispatch.<locals>._compiler_dispatch(self, visitor, **kw)
     78 except AttributeError as err:
---> 79     return visitor.visit_unsupported_compilation(self, err, **kw)
     81 else:

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py:536, in TypeCompiler.visit_unsupported_compilation(self, element, err, **kw)
    535 def visit_unsupported_compilation(self, element, err, **kw):
--> 536     util.raise_(
    537         exc.UnsupportedCompilationError(self, element),
    538         replace_context=err,
    539     )

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py:211, in raise_(***failed resolving arguments***)
    210 try:
--> 211     raise exception
    212 finally:
    213     # credit to
    214     # https://cosmicpercolator.com/2016/01/13/exception-leaks-in-python-2-and-3/
    215     # as the __traceback__ object creates a cycle

UnsupportedCompilationError: Compiler <sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.base.PGTypeCompiler object at 0x162ac95a0> can't render element of type SUPER (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/l7de)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

CompileError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[38], line 1
----> 1 test.to_sql('test', \
      2                     engine, \
      3                     schema = 'wbx_data_persistent', \
      4                     index = False, \
      5                     if_exists = 'replace', \
      6                     dtype = test_dict_types)

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:2987, in NDFrame.to_sql(self, name, con, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype, method)
   2830 """
   2831 Write records stored in a DataFrame to a SQL database.
   2832 
   (...)
   2983 [(1,), (None,), (2,)]
   2984 """  # noqa:E501
   2985 from pandas.io import sql
-> 2987 return sql.to_sql(
   2988     self,
   2989     name,
   2990     con,
   2991     schema=schema,
   2992     if_exists=if_exists,
   2993     index=index,
   2994     index_label=index_label,
   2995     chunksize=chunksize,
   2996     dtype=dtype,
   2997     method=method,
   2998 )

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py:695, in to_sql(frame, name, con, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype, method, engine, **engine_kwargs)
    690 elif not isinstance(frame, DataFrame):
    691     raise NotImplementedError(
    692         "'frame' argument should be either a Series or a DataFrame"
    693     )
--> 695 return pandas_sql.to_sql(
    696     frame,
    697     name,
    698     if_exists=if_exists,
    699     index=index,
    700     index_label=index_label,
    701     schema=schema,
    702     chunksize=chunksize,
    703     dtype=dtype,
    704     method=method,
    705     engine=engine,
    706     **engine_kwargs,
    707 )

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py:1728, in SQLDatabase.to_sql(self, frame, name, if_exists, index, index_label, schema, chunksize, dtype, method, engine, **engine_kwargs)
   1678 """
   1679 Write records stored in a DataFrame to a SQL database.
   1680 
   (...)
   1724     Any additional kwargs are passed to the engine.
   1725 """
   1726 sql_engine = get_engine(engine)
-> 1728 table = self.prep_table(
   1729     frame=frame,
   1730     name=name,
   1731     if_exists=if_exists,
   1732     index=index,
   1733     index_label=index_label,
   1734     schema=schema,
   1735     dtype=dtype,
   1736 )
   1738 total_inserted = sql_engine.insert_records(
   1739     table=table,
   1740     con=self.connectable,
   (...)
   1747     **engine_kwargs,
   1748 )
   1750 self.check_case_sensitive(name=name, schema=schema)

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py:1631, in SQLDatabase.prep_table(self, frame, name, if_exists, index, index_label, schema, dtype)
   1619             raise ValueError(f"The type of {col} is not a SQLAlchemy type")
   1621 table = SQLTable(
   1622     name,
   1623     self,
   (...)
   1629     dtype=dtype,
   1630 )
-> 1631 table.create()
   1632 return table

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py:838, in SQLTable.create(self)
    836         raise ValueError(f"'{self.if_exists}' is not valid for if_exists")
    837 else:
--> 838     self._execute_create()

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py:824, in SQLTable._execute_create(self)
    821 def _execute_create(self):
    822     # Inserting table into database, add to MetaData object
    823     self.table = self.table.to_metadata(self.pd_sql.meta)
--> 824     self.table.create(bind=self.pd_sql.connectable)

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py:962, in Table.create(self, bind, checkfirst)
    960 if bind is None:
    961     bind = _bind_or_error(self)
--> 962 bind._run_ddl_visitor(ddl.SchemaGenerator, self, checkfirst=checkfirst)

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:3228, in Engine._run_ddl_visitor(self, visitorcallable, element, **kwargs)
   3226 def _run_ddl_visitor(self, visitorcallable, element, **kwargs):
   3227     with self.begin() as conn:
-> 3228         conn._run_ddl_visitor(visitorcallable, element, **kwargs)

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:2211, in Connection._run_ddl_visitor(self, visitorcallable, element, **kwargs)
   2204 def _run_ddl_visitor(self, visitorcallable, element, **kwargs):
   2205     """run a DDL visitor.
   2206 
   2207     This method is only here so that the MockConnection can change the
   2208     options given to the visitor so that "checkfirst" is skipped.
   2209 
   2210     """
-> 2211     visitorcallable(self.dialect, self, **kwargs).traverse_single(element)

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py:524, in ExternalTraversal.traverse_single(self, obj, **kw)
    522 meth = getattr(v, "visit_%s" % obj.__visit_name__, None)
    523 if meth:
--> 524     return meth(obj, **kw)

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py:895, in SchemaGenerator.visit_table(self, table, create_ok, include_foreign_key_constraints, _is_metadata_operation)
    891 if not self.dialect.supports_alter:
    892     # e.g., don't omit any foreign key constraints
    893     include_foreign_key_constraints = None
--> 895 self.connection.execute(
    896     # fmt: off
    897     CreateTable(
    898         table,
    899         include_foreign_key_constraints=  # noqa
    900             include_foreign_key_constraints,  # noqa
    901     )
    902     # fmt: on
    903 )
    905 if hasattr(table, "indexes"):
    906     for index in table.indexes:

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1380, in Connection.execute(self, statement, *multiparams, **params)
   1376     util.raise_(
   1377         exc.ObjectNotExecutableError(statement), replace_context=err
   1378     )
   1379 else:
-> 1380     return meth(self, multiparams, params, _EMPTY_EXECUTION_OPTS)

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py:80, in DDLElement._execute_on_connection(self, connection, multiparams, params, execution_options)
     77 def _execute_on_connection(
     78     self, connection, multiparams, params, execution_options
     79 ):
---> 80     return connection._execute_ddl(
     81         self, multiparams, params, execution_options
     82     )

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1469, in Connection._execute_ddl(self, ddl, multiparams, params, execution_options)
   1465 schema_translate_map = exec_opts.get("schema_translate_map", None)
   1467 dialect = self.dialect
-> 1469 compiled = ddl.compile(
   1470     dialect=dialect, schema_translate_map=schema_translate_map
   1471 )
   1472 ret = self._execute_context(
   1473     dialect,
   1474     dialect.execution_ctx_cls._init_ddl,
   (...)
   1478     compiled,
   1479 )
   1480 if self._has_events or self.engine._has_events:

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py:503, in ClauseElement.compile(self, bind, dialect, **kw)
    498             url = util.preloaded.engine_url
    499             dialect = url.URL.create(
    500                 self.stringify_dialect
    501             ).get_dialect()()
--> 503 return self._compiler(dialect, **kw)

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py:32, in _DDLCompiles._compiler(self, dialect, **kw)
     28 def _compiler(self, dialect, **kw):
     29     """Return a compiler appropriate for this ClauseElement, given a
     30     Dialect."""
---> 32     return dialect.ddl_compiler(dialect, self, **kw)

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py:464, in Compiled.__init__(self, dialect, statement, schema_translate_map, render_schema_translate, compile_kwargs)
    462 if self.can_execute:
    463     self.execution_options = statement._execution_options
--> 464 self.string = self.process(self.statement, **compile_kwargs)
    466 if render_schema_translate:
    467     self.string = self.preparer._render_schema_translates(
    468         self.string, schema_translate_map
    469     )

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py:499, in Compiled.process(self, obj, **kwargs)
    498 def process(self, obj, **kwargs):
--> 499     return obj._compiler_dispatch(self, **kwargs)

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py:82, in _generate_compiler_dispatch.<locals>._compiler_dispatch(self, visitor, **kw)
     79     return visitor.visit_unsupported_compilation(self, err, **kw)
     81 else:
---> 82     return meth(self, **kw)

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py:4544, in DDLCompiler.visit_create_table(self, create, **kw)
   4542             first_pk = True
   4543     except exc.CompileError as ce:
-> 4544         util.raise_(
   4545             exc.CompileError(
   4546                 util.u("(in table '%s', column '%s'): %s")
   4547                 % (table.description, column.name, ce.args[0])
   4548             ),
   4549             from_=ce,
   4550         )
   4552 const = self.create_table_constraints(
   4553     table,
   4554     _include_foreign_key_constraints=create.include_foreign_key_constraints,  # noqa
   4555 )
   4556 if const:

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py:211, in raise_(***failed resolving arguments***)
    208     exception.__cause__ = replace_context
    210 try:
--> 211     raise exception
    212 finally:
    213     # credit to
    214     # https://cosmicpercolator.com/2016/01/13/exception-leaks-in-python-2-and-3/
    215     # as the __traceback__ object creates a cycle
    216     del exception, replace_context, from_, with_traceback

CompileError: (in table 'test', column 'y'): Compiler <sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.base.PGTypeCompiler object at 0x162ac95a0> can't render element of type SUPER
```

Comment: What's the `sqlalchemy-redshift==0.8.14` version? If not the latest, try to update it. `visit_SUPER` is not available in older versions

Comment: what does your code look like?

Comment: @shaikmoeed it said "Successfully installed sqlalchemy_redshift-0.8.14" Looks like that is the latest

Comment: Can you add the full traceback of the error?

Comment: @shaikmoeed added, hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your connecting string is using `postgresql` try to change it to `redshift`

From,

```
url = f"postgresql://..."
```

to,

```
url = f"redshift+psycopg2:..."
```

**Error details:**

As you are using Postgresql i.e., [`PGTypeCompiler`](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/8ecadd45d7afc5d510126226654f54ae67e42a4e/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/base.py#L2464) doesn't have `visit_SUPER` dialect.

If you check [RedshiftTypeCompiler](https://github.com/sqlalchemy-redshift/sqlalchemy-redshift/blob/main/sqlalchemy_redshift/dialect.py#L636), it contains the `visit_SUPER` dialect.

So, updating the connecting string to use `redshift` will fix the issue.